# Firebase child.once inconsistent timeout within auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword callback

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a simple nodejs service with firebase running in AWS EC2 (ubuntu). All I'm trying to do is use Firebase auth to login the user, and return the user information (additional info) on successful login.

Issue is, the call to retrive the user info from users object is getting timed out. Not all the time, it is inconsistent, and always when I try first time in the morning (or after few hours of idle server). What I have noticed from curl, is the first request of the day take a long time to return mostly 30+ seconds. (using free tier Firebase)

Could you please help me identifying what am I doing wrong? how can I resolve the issue?

Find the code below:

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
const users = firebase.database().ref('users');
const db = firebase.database();
/*
..a lot of code in between..
*/
let login = function(requestParam, callback) {
    console.log('userhandler.login called ' + new Date() + ' ' + requestParam.email)

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(requestParam.email, requestParam.password).catch((error)=>{
            console.log("error while signInWithEmailAndPassword " + error);
            console.log(new Date());
        }).then((userData) => {
            console.log('auth.signin .then called ' + new Date())
            console.log(userData.uid + ' ' + new Date());
            db.ref('/users/' + userData.uid).limitToFirst(1).once("value", (snapshot) => {
            // users.child(userData.uid).once("value", (snapshot) => {
                console.log('auth.signin.then.child.once called ' + new Date())
                let user = snapshot.val();
                callback(null, _.extend(user, {user_id : userData.uid}));
            }, (error) => {
                console.log('Error getting user list');
                callback(errors.authenticationFailure(error), null);
            }).catch((error) => {
                callback(error, null);
            });
        }, (error) => {
            console.log('Invalid Username or password');
            callback(errors.authenticationFailure(error), null);
        }).catch((error) => {
            callback(error, null);
        });

};
```

Noticed the same issue with both `users.child` and `db.ref('/users/id')`.

Nodejs logs below:

Request from my app (timed out at client end)

```
userhandler.login called Sun Oct 08 2017 13:10:05 GMT+0000 (UTC) MYUSERID@EMAIL.com
auth.signin .then called Sun Oct 08 2017 13:10:05 GMT+0000 (UTC)
rNmrXXXXXXXXXXXXZjuSDn2 Sun Oct 08 2017 13:10:05 GMT+0000 (UTC)
POST /api/users/login - - ms - -
```

Request from `curl`:

```
userhandler.login called Sun Oct 08 2017 13:11:57 GMT+0000 (UTC) MYUSERID@EMAIL.com
auth.signin .then called Sun Oct 08 2017 13:11:58 GMT+0000 (UTC)
rNmrXXXXXXXXXXXXZjuSDn2 Sun Oct 08 2017 13:11:58 GMT+0000 (UTC)
auth.signin.then.child.once called Sun Oct 08 2017 13:11:33 GMT+0000 (UTC)
POST /api/users/login 200 35319.714 ms - 273
```

Subsequent calls from whether it is from app or `curl` return response in < 500 ms:

```
userhandler.login called Sun Oct 08 2017 13:13:56 GMT+0000 (UTC) MYUSERID@EMAIL.com
auth.signin .then called Sun Oct 08 2017 13:13:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)
rNmrXXXXXXXXXXXXZjuSDn2 Sun Oct 08 2017 13:13:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)
auth.signin.then.child.once called Sun Oct 08 2017 13:13:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)
POST /api/users/login 200 489.888 ms - 273
```